# How to Show Velocity and Time Measurements in Manipulate (Wolfram Demonstrations)

Tags: manipulate, physics, data, scoping, time-series

I am working with a Wolfram Demonstration that uses the Manipulate function (which I am not yet familiar with).

The code is

```
Manipulate[
 
 dist = 5;
 
 posA = -dist;
 posB = dist;
 vA2 = -((-mA vA1 + ee mB vA1 - mB vB1 - ee mB vB1)/(mA + mB));
 vB2 = -((-mA vA1 - ee mA vA1 + ee mA vB1 - mB vB1)/(mA + mB));
 
 (* vA1*t-dist+mA/10=vB1*t+dist+mB/10, (vA1-vB1)*t=2*dist+mB/10 *)
 tImpact = (20 dist - mA - mB)/(10 (vA1 - vB1));
 
 posImpactA = posA + vA1*tImpact;
 posImpactB = posB + vB1*tImpact;
 
 If[tt <= tImpact, posA2 = vA1*tt + posA, 
  posA2 = posImpactA + vA2*(tt - tImpact)];
 If[tt <= tImpact, posB2 = vB1*tt + posB, 
  posB2 = posImpactB + vB2*(tt - tImpact)];
 
 If[tt <= tImpact, 
  vecB = Graphics[{Red, Thick, 
     Arrow[{{posB2, 0}, {posB2 + vB1, 0}}]}], 
  vecB = Graphics[{Darker[Green], 
     Arrow[{{posB2, 0}, {posB2 + vB2, 0}}]}]];
 If[tt <= tImpact, 
  vecA = Graphics[{Red, Thick, 
     Arrow[{{posA2, 0}, {posA2 + vA1, 0}}]}], 
  vecA = Graphics[{Darker[Green], Thick, 
     Arrow[{{posA2, 0}, {posA2 + vA2, 0}}]}]];
 
 parA = Graphics[{Darker[Gray], Disk[{posA2, 0}, mA/10]}];
 parB = Graphics[{Darker[Gray], Disk[{posB2, 0}, mB/10]}];
 road = Graphics[{Lighter[Gray], Line[{{-10, 0}, {10, 0}}]}];
 Show[{road, parA, parB, vecA, vecB}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-1, 5}}, ImageSize -> 450],
 {{mA, 5, "mass of A"}, 1, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{mB, 10, "mass of B"}, 1, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{vA1, 5, "initial velocity of A"}, 1, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{vB1, -5, "initial velocity of B"}, -5, 0, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{ee, 0.5, "coefficient of elasticity"}, 0, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{tt, 0, "time"}, 0, 5}, TrackedSymbols -> True,
 AutorunSequencing -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 6}]
```

I want to have as if there is a photogate at the center of the simulation that measures the velocity and outputs it in the animation. I would also want to output the corresponding times. In other words, I should have a time data column and a velocity data column but the velocity is just measured twice: once before it collides and once after it collides.

I tried the With function but it didn't work.

Here is my attempt:

```
Manipulate[
 With[{
   dist = 5;
   
   posA = -dist;
   posB = dist;
   vA2 = -((-mA vA1 + ee mB vA1 - mB vB1 - ee mB vB1)/(mA + mB)),
   vB2 = -((-mA vA1 - ee mA vA1 + ee mA vB1 - mB vB1)/(mA + mB))},
  
  (* vA1*t-dist+mA/10=vB1*t+dist+mB/10, (vA1-vB1)*t=2*dist+mB/10 *)
  tImpact = (20 dist - mA - mB)/(10 (vA1 - vB1));
  
  posImpactA = posA + vA1*tImpact;
  posImpactB = posB + vB1*tImpact;
  
  If[tt <= tImpact, posA2 = vA1*tt + posA, 
   posA2 = posImpactA + vA2*(tt - tImpact)];
  If[tt <= tImpact, posB2 = vB1*tt + posB, 
   posB2 = posImpactB + vB2*(tt - tImpact)];
  
  If[tt <= tImpact, 
   vecB = Graphics[{RGBColor[0., 0.18, 0.41], Thick, 
      Arrow[{{posB2, 0}, {posB2 + vB1, 0}}]}], 
   vecB = Graphics[{Darker[RGBColor[0.28, 0.39, 0.]], 
      Arrow[{{posB2, 0}, {posB2 + vB2, 0}}]}]];
  If[tt <= tImpact, 
   vecA = Graphics[{RGBColor[0., 0.18, 0.41], Thick, 
      Arrow[{{posA2, 0}, {posA2 + vA1, 0}}]}], 
   vecA = 
    Graphics[{Darker[RGBColor[0.28, 0.39, 0.]], Thick, 
      Arrow[{{posA2, 0}, {posA2 + vA2, 0}}]}]];
  
  parA = Graphics[{Darker[Gray], Disk[{posA2, 0}, mA/10]}];
  parB = Graphics[{Darker[Gray], Disk[{posB2, 0}, mB/10]}];
  road = Graphics[{Lighter[Gray], Line[{{-10, 0}, {10, 0}}]}]];
 Show[{road, parA, parB, vecA, vecB}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-1, 5}}, ImageSize -> 450],
 {{mA, 1, "mass of A"}, 1, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{mB, 10, "mass of B"}, 1, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{vA1, 5, "initial velocity of A"}, 1, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{vB1, 0, "initial velocity of B"}, -5, 0, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{ee, 0.5, "coefficient of elasticity"}, 0, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{tt, 0, "time"}, 0, 5}, TrackedSymbols -> True,
 AutorunSequencing -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 6}]
```

Any help would be so appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the velocities after collision stay constant, it is good enough to give the constant values. The velocities before collision are given as input. It makes therefore no sense to give a table with velocities at different times.

```
Manipulate[dist = 5;
 posA = -dist;
 posB = dist;
 vA2 = -((-mA vA1 + ee mB vA1 - mB vB1 - ee mB vB1)/(mA + mB));
 vB2 = -((-mA vA1 - ee mA vA1 + ee mA vB1 - mB vB1)/(mA + mB));
 (*vA1*t-dist+mA/10=vB1*t+dist+mB/10,(vA1-vB1)*t=2*dist+mB/10*)
 tImpact = (20 dist - mA - mB)/(10 (vA1 - vB1));
 posImpactA = posA + vA1*tImpact;
 posImpactB = posB + vB1*tImpact;
 If[tt <= tImpact, posA2 = vA1*tt + posA, 
  posA2 = posImpactA + vA2*(tt - tImpact)];
 If[tt <= tImpact, posB2 = vB1*tt + posB, 
  posB2 = posImpactB + vB2*(tt - tImpact)];
 If[tt <= tImpact, 
  vecB = Graphics[{Red, Thick, 
     Arrow[{{posB2, 0}, {posB2 + vB1, 0}}]}], 
  vecB = Graphics[{Darker[Green], 
     Arrow[{{posB2, 0}, {posB2 + vB2, 0}}]}]];
 If[tt <= tImpact, 
  vecA = Graphics[{Red, Thick, 
     Arrow[{{posA2, 0}, {posA2 + vA1, 0}}]}], 
  vecA = Graphics[{Darker[Green], Thick, 
     Arrow[{{posA2, 0}, {posA2 + vA2, 0}}]}]];
 parA = Graphics[{Darker[Gray], Disk[{posA2, 0}, mA/10]}];
 parB = Graphics[{Darker[Gray], Disk[{posB2, 0}, mB/10]}];
 road = Graphics[{Lighter[Gray], Line[{{-10, 0}, {10, 0}}]}];
 Column[{
   Show[{road, parA, parB, vecA, vecB}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-1, 5}}, ImageSize -> 450]
   , StringForm["Velocities after collision. A: ``, B: ``", vA2, vB2]}]
 , {{mA, 5, "mass of A"}, 1, 10, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{mB, 10, "mass of B"}, 1, 10, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{vA1, 5, "initial velocity of A"}, 1, 5, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{vB1, -5, "initial velocity of B"}, -5, 
  0, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{ee, 0.5, 
   "coefficient of elasticity"}, 0, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{tt, 0, "time"}, 0, 5}, 
 TrackedSymbols -> True, AutorunSequencing -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 6}]
```

[image]